# Python How to format column names of df after pivot_table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CaseNo':[1,1,2,2,2,2],
                    'Test1':['180','189','328','328','266','256'],
                    'Test2':['20','21','33','30','28','15'],
                    'Test3':['55','55','58','64','68','58'],
                    'Age':['65','65','45','45','45','45']})
```

[image]

In Python, after pivoting with this code:

```
df = (pd.pivot_table(s, index=["CaseNo","Age"],
                      aggfunc=["last", list]).reset_index())
```

I get this:
[image]
The columns look weird here. How can I format the cols to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Try - `df.columns = pd.Index(['_'.join(t) for t in df.columns]).str.strip('_')`